# T-SQL Query to match a set of ResultSet with a set of rows in DB, Group By columnId

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, mapping, combinations

This is the database schema we have.

[image: DB Schema]

**t_RoleCombinations** - These are all possible combination of Permissions a Role can have.

**t_Permissions_Hierarchy** - This enforces permissions. For e.g. if a role has permissions to `Create` some reosource, it should have the permissions to `Edit` that resource and if has permission to `Edit` it should have the permission to `View`. We also have a `Share` permission which if assigned should also enforce `View` permission. So, if a role has `Create` permission, it should also have `View` but might not have `Share` permission. Because of this complexity we cannot enforce hierarchy in a tree-view manner by having a ParentPermissionId column in t_Permissions and that is why have this t_PermissionHierarchy table.

**t_RoleCombinations_Permissions** - this is mapping table which actually defines all the combinations of permissions.

**Sample data of `t_Permissions` table**

[image: Sample Data of t_Permissions table]

**Sample data of `t_PermissionsHierarchy` table**

[image: Sample data of t_PermissionsHierarchy table]

When the client updates a Role, on the server I get a set of permissions which I need to match with one of the set in `t_RoleCombinations_Permissions` table and get a `RoleCombinationId` for it to be updated in `t_Roles` table. A comma separated value for set of permissions is passed in SP through parameter and I can make it recordset by a table valued function similar to the one [stated here](http://timdougall.net/Blog/Post/SQLSplitTableValuedFunction) if need be.

**UPDATE:-**

-I thought of creating a Varchar(Max) column in t_RoleCombinations to store comma separated sorted PermissionIds. But that's not good in a relational database.

-The statement I could think is below. But it won't work as `IN` operator checks logical `OR` and not `AND`.

```
SELECT RoleCombinationId from t_RoleCombinations_Permissions
WHERE PermissionId in (1,2,3,4,5) -- my comma saperated permissions
GROUP BY RoleCombinationId
HAVING Count(*) = 5 -- number of permissions specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. This is how I finally did it.

In this all code below, @permisionSet is this table variable into which all the comma separated permisionIds are inserted.

```
DECLARE @permissionSet TABLE (Id int, PermissionId bigint)
```

This is how I match the set of permissions with the combination already available. I got this idea from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2864890/148271#2865641).

```
SELECT @roleCombinationId = ISNULL(match.RoleCombinationId,0)
  FROM (
    SELECT RoleCombinationId
    FROM t_RoleCombinations_Permissions
    WHERE PermissionId IN (SELECT PermissionId FROM @permissionSet)
    GROUP BY RoleCombinationId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = @countt
  ) AS match
  INNER JOIN t_RoleCombinations_Permissions rcp ON match.RoleCombinationId = rcp.RoleCombinationId
  GROUP BY match.RoleCombinationId
  HAVING COUNT(*) = @countt
```

And this is how I validate a set of permissions against the hierarchy restrictions set in t_PermissionHierarchy table.

```
--If given set of permissions are valid
IF(
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT ph.PermissionId
                FROM @permissionSet ps
                INNER JOIN t_PermissionHierarchy ph ON ph.PermissionId = ps.PermissionId
                WHERE ph.ShouldHavePermissionId NOT IN (SELECT PermissionId FROM @permissionSet)
               )
   )
BEGIN
  --Permission set is valid. Insert it in t_RoleCombination_Pemissions table
END
```

And to find out which permissions are required but are missing in the set.

```
  WITH InvalidPerms AS (
    SELECT ph.PermissionId, ph.ShouldHavePermissionId
    FROM @permissionSet ps
    INNER JOIN t_PermissionHierarchy ph ON ph.PermissionId = ps.PermissionId
    WHERE ph.ShouldHavePermissionId NOT IN (SELECT PermissionId FROM @permissionSet)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT phh.PermissionId, phh.ShouldHavePermissionId
    FROM InvalidPerms ip
    INNER JOIN t_PermissionHierarchy phh ON phh.PermissionId = ip.ShouldHavePermissionId
    WHERE phh.ShouldHavePermissionId NOT IN (SELECT PermissionId FROM @permissionSet)
  )
  SELECT ShouldHavePermissionId FROM InvalidPerms
```